# Gilbert Strang, Linear Algebra, Problem 27 Section 3.3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Problem set 3 from MIT 18.06 in Spring 2010 ([solutions on OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/assignments/MIT18_06S10_pset3_s10_soln.pdf)) includes the following exercise (which is problem 27 in Section 3.3 of Gilbert Strang, *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, 4th ed. 2009):

> Suppose $R$ is $m$ by $n$ of rank $r$, with pivot columns first:
>   \begin{align}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I & F \\
> 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix} .
> \end{align}
>   [*Moderator remark:* Here, $R$ is supposed to be a matrix over the real numbers.]
>
> (a) What are the shapes of those four blocks?
>
> (b) Find a right-inverse $B$ with $RB = I$ if $r = m$.
>
> (c) Find a left-inverse $C$ with $CR = I$ if $r = n$.
>
> (d) What is the reduced row echelon form of $R^T$ (with shapes)?
>
> (e) What is the reduced row echelon form of $R^T R$ (with shapes)?
>
> Prove that $R^T R$ has the same nullspace as $R$. Later we show that $A^T A$ always has the same nullspace as $A$ (a valuable fact).

I do not understand the solution for question e, in particular the matrix block multiplication. I do not understand where the 0 matrix block comes from. When I perform the multiplication, I come up with (F transpose) time (F) instead...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k3EP.png)

Comment: David Gilbert must be the bastard child of David Hilbert and Gilbert Strang, right? (Sorry, couldn't resist. Fixed, of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rename the $r \times r$ identity matrix $I$ as $I_r$. Then,
\begin{align}
R = \begin{pmatrix} I_r & F \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
(in block form), thus
\begin{align}
R^T = \begin{pmatrix} I_r^T & 0^T \\ F^T & 0^T \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ F^T & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
(in block form). Hence, the rule for multiplying block matrices yields
\begin{align}
R^T R = \begin{pmatrix} I_r I_r + 0 \cdot 0 & I_r F + 0 \cdot 0 \\ F^T I_r + 0 \cdot 0 & F^T F + 0 \cdot 0 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} I_r & F \\ F^T & F^T F \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
... and you're right, this is not what the solutions claim. I think there is a typo in the solutions, because the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} I_r & F \\ F^T & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ usually has rank larger than $r$, while $R^T R$ has rank $r$. In such cases, I would normally recommend messaging the author of the solutions to point out the mistake, but I have no idea how easy it is to update an old OCW course (my impression is that it involves some indirections).

Now, how do we get the rref of $R^T R$ from this? Well, we can get it in a simpler way: It is easy to see that $R^T = \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ F^T & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is row-equivalent to $X := \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, because $R^T = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ F^T & I_r \end{pmatrix}}_{\text{an invertible $m \times m$-matrix}} X$. Hence, $R^T R$ is row-equivalent to $X R = \begin{pmatrix} I_r & F \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which is already a reduced row echelon matrix. This is precisely the rref claimed by Strang.

Answer (score 0):

Also I think that the product of the book it's wrong and instead of 0 there is $F^t\cdot F$